# C Sockets Issue

Tags: c, sockets, fault

I am running a client which sends from the command line a timezone, and a test server (which we know works), returns the date and time for that timezone. However after returning the timezones, correctly, it segfaults.

Below is my client code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
char buf[kBufSize+1];
char line[128];
ssize_t n;
int i;
int more;
int x = 0; 

int sockFD;
int port;
struct sockaddr_in sad;
struct hostent *ptrh;

sockFD = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
memset(&sad, 0, sizeof(sad));                 /* Sets every byte of the address to be zero */
  sad.sin_family = AF_INET; 

/* Look up name */
ptrh = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
memcpy(&sad.sin_addr, ptrh->h_addr, ptrh->h_length);

/* Set port */
//sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &port);
port = atoi(argv[2]);
//printf("%d",port);
sad.sin_port = htons(port);

int clifd = connect(sockFD, (struct sockaddr *)&sad, sizeof(sad));
if(clifd < 0) {
    printf("[ERROR]: Error Connecting...\n");
    return 0;
}
printf("Number of args: %d\n", argc);
x = 3;

    //printf("Value of x: %d\n", x);
    //printf("[DEBUG]: Value of X: %d\n", x);

    //printf("[DEBUG]: Line: %s\n", line);
    do
    {
        /* Read input line */
        do
        {
            more = 1;
            n = read(sockFD, buf, kBufSize);
            buf[n] = '\0'; // BUF IS READ FROM THE SERVER

            if(n <= 0)
                break;

            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if(buf[i] == 10)
                {
                    more = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }

            printf("%s", buf);

            if (buf == "BYE\r\n"){
                printf("Closing\n");
                exit(1);
            }

        } while(more);

        if(n <= 0)
        {
        break;
        }
        strcpy(line, argv[x]);
        strcat(line, "\r\n\0"); // LINE IS SENT TO THE SERVER
        //printf("[DEBUG] Being sent: %s", line);
        write(sockFD, line, strlen(line));
        //printf("%d", n);
        //printf("Value of x: %d\n", x);
        x++;
    } while (n != 0 && x <= argc);

   close(sockFD);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: debugger, use one :)

Comment: "*it segfaults.*" also the English language is context dependant.

Comment: You can't compare strings like this `buf == "BYE\r\n"` in C. Use `strcmp()`.

Comment: Why this: `x = 3;`?

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Comment: If you wish others examine your code, at least indent it properly, as a basic courtesy...

Answer (score 1):

The argv array goes from 0 to argc-1 but you are using argv from 3 to argc. Look at the condition on your outer do/while loop.